# Phonegap FILE_URI, source of image

Tags: cordova, camera, file-uri

Got a problem with Phonegap and the camera plugin. I'm trying to display the taken photo in my view, but it doesn't work. I can make it work with DATA_URL, but I need it to work with FILE_URI (because they advice that!)

This is my code, but i guess its not in the code, because with DATA_URL it works, but with the FILE_URI it doesn't, although I have exactly the same code as in the docs.

```
$('#uploadBusinessCard').on('click', function() {
    console.log("capture this foto!");
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 10,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    });
});

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    console.log("on success!");
    var image = document.getElementById('myImageIdee');
    image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

The code that works is almost the same:

```
$('#uploadBusinessCard').on('click', function() {
    console.log("capture this foto!");
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 10,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    });
});

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImageIdee');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: in which platform? device? os version?

Comment: I'm only making use of iOS, on an iPad 2 which has the iOS version of 7

I'm now checking if I can get the source of the image and upload that source to my PHP server, and fill in that URL in the Database. I know this is way more complicator than just uploading the direct image, but it's not working and I must go on...

Comment: is the onSuccess getting called? can you log the url?

Comment: Yes the onSuccess is getting called. Funny thing is, the right URL is logged in the console. file://var/etc/etc/etc/picture_14.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the phonegap desktop app and the phonegap developer app on the ipad, there is a knonw issue that doesn't show the images if you use the FILE_URI

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/174

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/248

Comment: Thanks. This is the confirmation I need. Probably it works as intended, only I cannot test it via the phone developer app.

Comment: it's happened to me too, on real device when run `ionic run android --live-reload` (this command install the application on my device and refreshed anytime i made changes in code)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
$('#uploadBusinessCard').on('click', function() {
    console.log("capture this foto!");
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, {
        quality: 10,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: true
    });
});

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    console.log("on success!");
    var image = document.getElementById('myImageIdee');
    image.style.display = 'block';
    image.src = imageURI;
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Comment: I think you added the "saveToPhotoAlbum: true", which is nice, but it's not working. I found it very odd though. I have multiple console.logs and after I changed the source of the image identifier, and I check the image.src and I console.log that, it says exactly the image path, but still it isn;t showing up :S

Comment: Could it be that because I am using the Phonegap desktop application to "stream" the app over WiFi to my iPad to test things out, its because of that its not working? Because when I change a small thing in the code it prepends the ip address of the phonegap server in front of the line of code... That could be a problem which is not overseen

Comment: The image now disappears, instead of saying no file found... So that is a step in the right direction.

Comment: so you are using the phonegap desktop app and the phonegap ios app to test your code? you should have mentioned that

Comment: it can run only in mobile phone, not desktop.